# XSLT 2.0 test tokenized results for no value

Tags: xslt-2.0

In XSLT 2.0 I am handling a string delimited by `~`. There are times that the tokenized results contain an instance of 'nothing' between two `~`. I try to test for this using `empty()`

```
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize($list_of_items,'~')">
    <xsl:if test="not(empty(.))">
    ...do something here...
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

...which [doesn't work](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_empty.html). What is the correct way to test for nothing/empty/blank value in a tokenized list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tokenize` gives you a sequence of strings, if you have an input with two adjacent separator characters (e.g. `tokenize('foo~~bar', '~')`) then you get an empty string so `tokenize($list_of_items,'~')[not(. = '')]` should do to exclude empty strings.